# Read word from file

Tags: c

I got a txt file with words and them definitions, with semicolon and different space between, also every word with definition in new line. It looks like that:

I got a code, but I don't know how to read from file and then search by letter. Thanks for your help.

I got a code, but I don't know how to read from file and then search by letter. Thanks for your help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

int main(){
    ifstream input;
    input.open("dictionary.txt"); 

    if(!input.is_open()){
        cout << "Error" << endl;
    } 

    else{
        char ch;
        string str; 

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
                cout << "Reading file";
                cout << " " << i << endl;
                sleep(0);
                system("cls");
        } 

        cout << "File was open" << endl;
        sleep(0);
        cout.flush();
        system("cls"); 

        int choise;
        
        menu:
        cout << "1. Starting\n2. Containing\n3. Ending\n4. Stop\nInput your choise: ";
        cin >> choise;
        system("cls"); 

        switch(choise){
            case 1:{   // searching by 1 letter
                cout << "Input letter: "
                goto menu;
            } 

            case 2:{  // searching by any letter in word
                goto menu;
            } 

            case 3:{  // searching by last letter 
                 goto menu;
            } 

            case 4:{
                system("cls");
                cout << "Closing file" << endl;
                sleep(2);
                break;
            } 

            default:{
                cout << "Input 1-4!" << endl;
                goto menu;
            }
        }
    } 

    input.close();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use correct C++ code to do the task.

With modern C++ elements and algorithms.

And, especially, by really using all iostream facilities.

One example could be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

struct TermDefinition {
    // The data
    std::string term{};
    std::string definition{};
    // Override extractor operator
    friend std::istream& operator >> (std::istream& is, TermDefinition& td) {
        std::getline(std::getline(is, td.term, ';') >> std::ws, td.definition);
        return is;
    }
    // Overwrite inserter operator
    friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, const TermDefinition& td) {
        return os << td.term << " - " << td.definition;
    }
};

int main() {
    // Open file and check, if it could be opened
    if (std::ifstream dictionaryStream{ "dictionary.txt" }; dictionaryStream) {

        // Read complete file. Split it into components. Add to vector
        std::vector dictionary(std::istream_iterator<TermDefinition>(dictionaryStream), {});

        // As long as we should run the program, do the loop
        bool runProgram{ true };
        while (runProgram) {

            // Get teh election for the user. Check for errors in input
            std::cout << "\n\nMenu. Please select\n\n1 -> Starting\n2 -> Containing\n3 -> Ending\n4 -> Stop\n\nPlease enter 1 or 2 or 3 or 4: ";
            if (unsigned int selection{}; std::cin >> selection) {

                // Depending on selction gieven by user
                switch (selection) {
                case 1:
                    // Give instruction to user
                    std::cout << "\n\nSearching by first letter. Enter letter: ";

                    // Get one letter from user and check for valid input
                    if (std::string letter{}; std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, letter) && letter.length() == 1)

                        // Copy all dictionary entries fullfilling the search criteria to std::cout
                        std::copy_if(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TermDefinition>(std::cout, "\n"), 
                            [&letter](const TermDefinition& td) { return *td.term.begin() == letter[0]; });
                    break;
                case 2:
                    // Give instruction to user
                    std::cout << "\n\nSearching by any letter. Enter letter: ";

                    // Get one letter from user and check for valid input
                    if (std::string letter{}; std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, letter) && letter.length() == 1)

                        // Copy all dictionary entries fullfilling the search criteria to std::cout
                        std::copy_if(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TermDefinition>(std::cout, "\n"),
                            [&letter](const TermDefinition& td) { return td.term.find(letter[0]) != std::string::npos; });
                    break;
                case 3:
                    // Give instruction to user
                    std::cout << "\n\nSearching by last letter. Enter letter: ";

                    // Get one letter from user and check for valid input
                    if (std::string letter{}; std::getline(std::cin >> std::ws, letter) && letter.length() == 1)

                        // Copy all dictionary entries fullfilling the search criteria to std::cout
                        std::copy_if(dictionary.begin(), dictionary.end(), std::ostream_iterator<TermDefinition>(std::cout, "\n"),
                            [&letter](const TermDefinition& td) { return td.term.back() == letter[0]; });
                    break;
                case 4:
                    // User wants to stop the program
                    // Set loop flag to 0
                    runProgram = false;
                    std::cout << "\n\nDone. Exiting program . . .\n\n";
                    break;
                default:
                    std::cout << "\n\nInvalid number. Please try again\n\n";
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                std::cout << "\n\nError: Invalid input. Please try again\n\n\n";
                // Reset bad input state an consume nonesense characters
                std::cin.clear();
                std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            }
        }
    }
    else std::cerr << "\n\nError: Could not open input file!\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

You already accepted the other answer. So, my guess is that you do no read this and therefore do not need further explanations. Otherwise, please comment and I will add explanations.

Comment: It has an error in line where you reding file and adding to vector

Comment: No, no error. It has been compiled and tested. You must enable C++17.

Comment: Ok, i trying another method  with loop while(getline) and then split definition and discripton in string by stringstream inside of while loop

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how your problem could be solved. I've wrote string searching code, dictionary elements load code and rewrote the input cycle removing gotos. The code still contains problems, for example only 3 elements of the dictionary are loaded.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream> 
#include <unistd.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct mydictionary
{
  string sDefinition;
  string sDescription;
};

void PrintByFirstLetter(const std::vector<mydictionary>& dict, char letter) {
    for (auto &istr: dict) {
        if( istr.sDefinition.length() && *istr.sDefinition.begin() == letter)
            cout << istr.sDefinition << " - " << istr.sDescription << endl;
    }
}

void PrintByLastLetter(const std::vector<mydictionary>& dict, char letter) {
    for (auto &istr: dict) {
        if( istr.sDefinition.length() && *(--istr.sDefinition.end()) == letter)
            cout << istr.sDefinition << " - " << istr.sDescription << endl;
    }
}

void PrintByAnyLetter(const std::vector<mydictionary>& dict, char letter) {
    for (auto &istr: dict) {
        //if (istr.sDefinition.find(letter) != istr.sDefinition.end())
        if (istr.sDefinition.find(letter) != std::string::npos)
            cout << istr.sDefinition << " - " << istr.sDescription << endl;
    }
}

int main(){
    ifstream input("dictionary.txt");

    if(!input.is_open()) {
        cout << "Failed to open dictionary" << endl;
    } 
    else {
        mydictionary mdc;
        std::vector<mydictionary> dict;

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                cout << "Reading file";
                cout << " " << i << endl;

                std::getline(input, mdc.sDefinition, ';');
                cout << mdc.sDefinition << endl;
                std::getline(input, mdc.sDescription);
                cout << mdc.sDescription << endl;
                dict.push_back(mdc);

                sleep(0);
                system("cls");
        } 

        cout << "File was open" << endl;
        sleep(0);
        cout.flush();
        system("cls");

        int choise;
        do
        {
            cout << "1. Starting\n2. Containing\n3. Ending\n4. Stop\nInput your choise: ";
            cin >> choise;
            system("cls"); 

            if(choise >= 1 && choise <= 3) {
                char letter;
                cout << "Input letter:";
                cin >> letter;
                if( choise == 1) // searching by 1 letter
                    PrintByFirstLetter(dict, letter);
                else if( choise == 2) // searching by any letter in word
                    PrintByAnyLetter(dict, letter);
                else if( choise == 3) // searching by last letter
                    PrintByLastLetter(dict, letter);
            }
            else if(choise == 4) {
                system("cls");
                cout << "Closing file" << endl;
                sleep(2);
                break;
            } 
            else
                cout << "Input 1-4!" << endl;
        } while(1);
    }
}
```